# drush cannot update commerce kickstart

Tags: drush, commerce

I just installed [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and got a prompt to upgrade from 7.x-2.20 to 7.x-2.21.
drush cannot update throws error:
`The commerce_kickstart directory could not be found within the modules directory at                          [error]
/var/www/planetwigs.com/profiles/commerce_kickstart, perhaps the project is enabled but has been deleted from
disk.`
Now, the directory exists and the modules are there.
In the GUI I am offered the option to download module, which I did and replaced all modules with new version, just overwrote since I did not modify anything yet and the old sftp method worked, but drush did not.
BTW it is impossible to use the dropdown to selected version 2.20

Answer (score 0):

Drush update for commerce kickstart is not just update drush pm-update, but rather:

drush dl commerce_kickstart
drush updatedb

[Check here](https://drupalcommerce.org/blog/9072/updating-commerce-kickstart-2)